# I want to put a slider in a slidedown div

Tags: javascript, html

I want to put this slider in the slideDown() function so that when the text is hovered the slider should come down.

I have given the code snippet that i was trying to work on, it includes the javascript, css, body.

```
    <script> 

    var $ = function (id) {
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}


var swapImage = function (){

if($("image1").title=="image1")
{
    $("image1").src="/static/img/new_desserts/two.jpg";
    $("image1").title="image2";
}
else if($("image1").title=="image2")
    {
        $("image1").src="/static/img/new_desserts/teen.jpg";
        $("image1").title="image3";
    } 
else if($("image1").title=="image3")
    {
        $("image1").src="/static/img/new_desserts/some.jpg";
        $("image1").title="image4";
    }
else if($("image1").title=="image4")
    {
        $("image1").src="/static/img/new_desserts/set.jpg";
        $("image1").title="image5";
    }
else if($("image1").title=="image5")
    {
        $("image1").src="/static/img/new_desserts/cake.jpg";
        $("image1").title="image1";
    }
    setTimeout(swapImage, 5000);
}

window.onload = function () {
   /*  $("calculate=").onclick = function(){calculate();} */

   swapImage();
}

$(document).ready(function(){

          $("#prj_1").mouseover(function(){
            $("#image").stop().slideDown("slow");
    });


});
</script>

<style>
            #prj_1{
                position:absolute;
                top:1%;
                left:50%;
                width:1230px;
                height:200px;
                font-family:Andalus;
                font-size:20px;
                color:gold; 
            }
            #image{
                position:absolute;
                top:3%;
                left:25%;
                width:700px;
                height:300px;
                display:none;   
                background-color:red;
            }
</style>

<body>
        <div id="prj_1">AAA Laundry</div>

         <div id="image">
                <img id="image1" src="/static/img/new_desserts/glass.jpg" title="image1" />
        </div>


    </div>

</body>
```

if i remove the code for slideDown its working but otherwise it not. 
please help.

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little and used JQuery instead of Javascript,
also you used `window.onload` and `$(document).ready` which have almost the same purpose.

plz check this demo and see if that's what you wanted:-

http://jsfiddle.net/d3rtcyxn/

Comment: Thank u soo much, this is exactly what i wanted.